# Asynchronous Kitten Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've been using Mongoose to query MongoDb during a web request something like:

```
Kittens.find()
.where('born')
.gt(startDate)
.lt(endDate)
.exec(function (err, kittens) {
    if (err) {
    // bad kitty
    }

    // fun with kittens

    res.jsonp(kittenData);
});
```

Unfortunately, if I have too many kittens [this happens](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/deBoTrPFgc4)

So I need to do this to reduce the amount of data I pull back:

```
get real start date and real end date
make temp start date and temp end date
   get one days worth of kittens
   increment the temp dates by one
   until temp end date is past real end date
```

The problem with this is that I tried to declare:

```
var allKittens = [];
```

And then within the loop where I query a days worth of kittens:

```
allKittens.concat(todaysKittens);
```

but `allKittens` tends to still be an empty array.

I'm not a Javascript Ninja, so I don't know how I run this async kitten query numerous times and concatenate all the kittens I need into a single array that I can use when I send my response.

Pwease Help Me

Comment: Use `push` instead of `concat`.

Comment: If you wish to use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) then you'll need to assign the return to the existing array (to retain what was added to the array).  Something like `allKittens = allKittens.concat(todaysKittens);`